# Cannot locate python node

Tags: ros, roslaunch, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When executing my launch file, I get the error

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [package/node.py]: Cannot locate node of type [node.py] in package [robot]

for every node in the launch file. This script was working about 8 hours ago, and no files have been changed. Tried re-running rosmake.

using roslib.packages.findnode returns nothing for any node/package pair in the project.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10092/cannot-locate-python-node/) by [bostonian](https://answers.ros.org/users/612/bostonian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-05-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If no files have been changed, it's a bit of mystery, but the only time I have run into this error in the past when a node script is really in the right place pointed to by the launch file is that the execute bit on the script is not set.  To fix: "chmod 755 node.py".  But I'm guessing you have already checked this.  You could also try running "make clean" followed by "rosmake" in the package directory as well as "rospack profile".

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2011-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hitimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23510/hitimo/) on 2015-08-09**:
+1 I had an similar problem with a ros launch-file. `chmod 744 node.launch` did the magic for me.